# Is there any Heroku command to open my app's code?

Tags: heroku

I need to check my app codes in Heroku. By mistake I deleted some code in a file locally but it already hosted on Heroku and I need to write it back locally, so that's why I want to know is there any Heroku command to open the app code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you deployed to Heroku via `git push` you should be able to [clone your code via Heroku's Git service](https://help.heroku.com/FZDDCBLB/how-can-i-download-my-code-from-heroku):

```
heroku git:clone <your-app-name>
```

If you already have a local repository connected to Heroku you can try `git fetch` or `git pull` as well.

Note that, although this may help you today, it [isn't meant to be part of your primary workflow](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app):

> Heroku provides the git service primarily for deployment, and the ability to clone from it is offered as a convenience. We strongly recommend you store your code in another git repository such as [GitHub](https://github.com/) and treat that as canonical.

(Also, if you *do* have a local repository, your previously deployed code should exist in one or more revisions in that repository. Local Git commands like `git checkout <revision-hash> -- <path/to/file>` are probably a simpler, more direct way to retrieve your code.)

Comment: Tacking on an extra comment here. If you don't use the deploy by git workflow this won't work. For example, if you deploy via github or (formerly) Dropbox, the Heroku git servers won't have a copy of the repo. In that case, you can either run `heroku run bash` and inspect the code that way.